# Meaning of 'prime', 'set'. Theater dance

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I've encountered such phrases inside an agreement document:

a)

> ...at the completion of each four **primes**..

or

> DANCER will participate in all dances prepared for the **prime**

The context here is *dancing*, *performance*. Both **show** and **prime** are present in the document but I don't know whether they are synonyms.

b)

> DANCER at all times **on set**, rehearsals, stage will be respectful, calm and represent well the 
>   artistic image of COMPANY.

What does **set** mean here?

Comment: 1) please show more context. 2) Film set. Whenever the dancers are on a film set, at rehearsals and on a stage ...

Comment: To add to mplungjan’s comment, 2) does not necessarily need to be a _film_ set. The area where a dance performance is rehearsed and performed is also a set, so the dancer will be _on set_ when doing so.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I thought about this. I find it strange to use stage and set here together.

Comment: I presume they mean that a dancer is on set when they are behind the curtain, in the dressing room, etc., as well as when they are actually on the stage performing.

Comment: Plus lawyers are fond of redundancy, as in "last will and testament".

Comment: Since these are two different questions, perhaps you should ask them as such. (Right now, rajah9's upvoted answer to the second question means that the system thinks this question is completely answered, so as time goes on, it'll be less and less likely that the first question will ever get an answer.)

Comment: -1 for not enough context in the quotes.  Please edit question and include quotes with subjects, verbs, and objects.  (Irrelevant parts can be left out, indicated by ellipses.)  *Prime* might be a noun or it might be an adjective in some of the quotes as given, and more context is necessary to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*On set* parallels the film and theater world. The *set* would include more than *stage*, which is visible to the audience, but also *backstage*.

I might alter the wording of the last statement. Perhaps they meant:

> When DANCERS are on set (either in rehearsal or on stage), they will be respectful, calm, ...

This would mean that they agree to behave not just when on stage, but also off stage (perhaps waiting for a cue or between acts).

Comment: I'm less sure about *prime*, but perhaps it is meant to encompass both the terms *prima ballerina* (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ballet_dancer) and *premier danseur* (male counterpart). Were there four prime dancers named in the agreement?

Comment: no, they weren't.